# Washing cat toys made of fabric/absorbent material

Tags: cats, toys, poison

I have some toy mice that are infused with catnip so the cats are really chewing on them. The toys are soaked through with their saliva.

How should I wash the toys when they are done? I understand that washing it will definitely reduce the effectiveness of the catnip, but I'm not overly concerned with that.

I am however concerned that using detergents or soaps may leave harmful chemicals. Also, soaps may leave smells that cats dislike and that would render the toy completely ineffective regardless of catnip.

What kinds of soap can/should I use? What are the chemicals in soaps that I must most definitely avoid? Can I use baking soda since it's odourless?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Dreft](https://dreft.com/en-us) baby liquid detergent for my puppy's soft toys. It has been working fine. I would think any baby clothing detergent would be suitable and safe.